# Parsing BST Timezone

Tags: objective-c, ios, timezone, nsdateformatter

I'm having problems parsing a date which has 'BST' as its timezone.

This is the date: `2012-04-22 16:00:00 BST`

And this is my code

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate * matchDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

This works well with GMT for example, but for BST I'm getting nil, any clue?

Comment: can you post exact input string examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BST is a date format considered a [metazone](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns), therefore you should parse it using the `V` syntax.

I would suggest changing your parse string to:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss V"];
```

the use of the quotes around the ZZZ, means that the parser should expect the *text* ZZZ, rather than a timezone

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know about those Metazones!